# Autostarting applications in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I've just created a new build for Lubuntu 18.04 and i'm trying to get an application to auto-start when any user logs in.

I did try and put the .desktop file of the application in to the ~/.config/lxsession/lubuntu/autostart directory but it looks like it's broken it!

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Just in case you don't get an answer here, you could try asking at [ubuntu.se] instead

Comment: If you want ubuntu to start an application when any user opened it, you can easily add an application or remove. Just search on ubuntu "Startup Applications" and use the program interface to add or remove any application.